# Cannot inject Templating on Symfony 4 Service

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have the following class:

**EmailNotification**

```
namespace App\Component\Notification\RealTimeNotification;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

use App\Component\Notification\NotificationInterface;

class EmailNotification implements NotificationInterface
{   
    private $logNotification;

    public function __construct(LogNotification $logNotification, \Swift_Mailer $mailer,  EngineInterface $twigEngine)
    {
        $this->logNotification = $logNotification;
    }

    public function send(array $options): void
    {
        $this->logNotification->send($options);

        dump('Sent to email');
    }
}
```

I have the following service definition on my yml:

```
app.email_notification:
    class: App\Component\Notification\RealTimeNotification\EmailNotification
    decorates: app.log_notification
    decoration_inner_name: app.log_notification.inner
    arguments: ['@app.log_notification.inner', '@mailer', '@templating']
```

However, when i tried to run my app it throws an Exception saying:

> Cannot autowire service
>   "App\Component\Notification\RealTimeNotification\EmailNotification":
>   argument "$twigEngine" of method "__construct()" has type
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface" but this
>   class was not found.

Why is that so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely you don't have Templating included in your project, in Symfony 4 you have to require it explicitly:

```
composer require symfony/templating
```

Comment: I actually have, I tripled check it.

Comment: What I inject now is \Twig_Environment, i think this would suffice for now.

Comment: @iamjc015 When you run `php bin/console debug:autowiring` do you see `Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface` class? It should be an alias to `templating.engine.twig`. Do you have `templating` entry in your framework.yaml file?

Comment: i don't see EngineInterface. Maybe thats the problem, why is that so?

Comment: and i don't have templating. Yeah, no symfony/templating :(

Comment: @iamjc015 I've just used your suggestion, works great. Thanks! There is a typo in your comment though, for Sf4 I had to use \Twig\Environment

Comment: `symfony/templating` is deprecated since Symfony 4.3. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380813/1668200 for a solution.

Answer (score 30):

You have to install symfony/templating

```
composer require symfony/templating
```

change a little bit config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines:
            - twig
```

Comment: For those wondering, you have to add the config part in `framework.yaml` for autowiring to load the Templating component.

Comment: Any more info to add to this? I get an error `You have requested a non-existent service "templating.engine.twig". ... I have installed `composer require symfony/templating`?

Comment: I am not sure if that is what helped, but I what is did is: `composer require twig` and after that I was able to use `'@templating'`

Comment: `symfony/templating` is deprecated since Symfony 4.3. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380813/1668200 for a solution.

Answer (score 25):

I managed to do it with Twig Environment and HTTP Response

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Twig\Environment;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyClass
{
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function renderTemplateAction($msg)
    {
        return new Response($this->twig->render('myTemplate.html.twig'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the preferred way since Symfony 4.3 as the "templating" component has been deprecated. One dependency less!