# Symfony 4.3: User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0 …

Tags: php, symfony, twig

After upgrading to Symfony 4.3, I'm getting the following 22 deprecation warnings:

> User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig notation for templates instead.
>
> User Deprecated: The **"templating.locator"** service is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0.
>
> User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> User Deprecated: The **"templating.name_parser"** service is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0.
>
> User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> User Deprecated: Using the **"templating"** service is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use \Twig\Environment instead.
>
> User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface interface is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use \Twig\Environment instead.
>
> 2 times: The **"framework.templating"** configuration is deprecated since Symfony 4.3. Configure the **"twig"** section provided by the Twig Bundle instead.
>
> Enabling the Templating component is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> The **"templating.cache_warmer.template_paths"** service is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0.
>
> The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplatePathsCacheWarmer class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> The **"templating.finder"** service is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0.
>
> The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateFinder class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateFinderInterface interface is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> The **"templating.locator"** service is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0.
>
> The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.
>
> The **"templating.name_parser"** service is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0.
>
> The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig instead.

Comment: You need to update the `symfony/framework-bundle`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is due to the deprecation of the templating component, see https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-deprecated-the-templating-component-integration

Solution:

1. Remove `"symfony/templating"` from `composer.json`
2. Remove this from `framework.yaml`:

   ```
   templating:
       engines:
           - twig
   ```
3. Run `composer update`

This should remove all the deprecation warnings.

If you're getting this error

> Cannot autowire service "...": argument "$templating" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

... you're still using the old templating in some service.
Solution: Change the dependency from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface` to `Twig\Environment`:

```php
use Twig\Environment;

private $twig;

public function __construct(Environment $twig)
{
    $this->twig = $twig;
}
```

See also https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31645

Comment: The blog post says the _framework integration_ of the templating component is deprecated, not the component itself.

Comment: @Eugene, fabpot says clearly "You should not use symfony/templating anymore with Twig.".

Comment: @Aerendir yes, which means the twig framework integration. See his comment under the blog post: *"We already have a PHP template engine (Templating component, which is still here and stable). What we removed is the integration with the framework as it was not maintained and not used."* -- Fabien Potencier https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-deprecated-the-templating-component-integration
Just deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in config/packages/framework.yaml: `templating` with `fragments`:

[image: Replace in config/packages/framework.yaml: templating with fragments]

Source: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-deprecated-the-templating-component-integration